# unity/c#: data from another gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I want in my Unity game, to get a float of another GameObject.
The Gameonject is called "Spawner", the script on the GameObject "CarZSpawner" and the float in the script "mult". The float "mult ist changing every few seconds."

i tried many things but nothing works, and i can't find anything on the internet :(

```
public class TrainScript : MonoBehaviour
{
void Update()
      {
           float test = GameObject.Find("Spawner").GetComponent<CarScriptZ.mult>()
      }
}
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your Script Name on the GameObject with the name "Spawner" called "CarZSpawner"? In your code you try to get a script with the name "CarScriptZ". Or do you have a Gameobject with the name "CarZSpawner" with the script "CarScriptZ"? If its so you look for the script in the wrong GameObject.

Comment: In any case, you should never ever use **GameObject.Find** in an Update function. You can create a variable and hold a reference to Spawner in the **Awake or Start** function. Also, what error do you get when running the code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty that your script is called `CarScriptZ` and `mult` is rather the field you are trying to access so it should be

```
float test = GameObject.Find("Spawner").GetComponent<CarScriptZ>().mult;
```

Besides that you should store the references **once** e.g. in `Start` and then re-use it later like

```
// If possible already reference this via the Inspector by drag & drop
[SerializeField] private CarScriptZ carScriptZ; 

private void Start()
{ 
    // As fallback get it ONCE on runtime
    if(!carScriptZ) carScriptZ = GameObject.Find("Spawner").GetComponent<CarScriptZ>(); 
} 

private void Update()
{
    float test = carScriptZ.mult; 
}
```